# Implement a template function that takes two classes as template parameters and returns true if they are inherited

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Below is the code i have come across that actually does the job of `std::is_base_of` function in C++11 or `boost::is_base_of`.

Below helper function does the same:

```
template<typename D, typename B>
class IsDerivedFromHelper
{
   class No { };
   class Yes { No no[3]; };

   static Yes Test( B* );
   static No Test( ... );
public:
    enum { Is = sizeof(Test(static_cast<D*>(0))) == sizeof(Yes) };

};


template <class C, class P> 
bool IsDerivedFrom() {
 return IsDerivedFromHelper<C, P>::Is;
}
```

Can someone explain what excatly the enum `Is` does?

What are static `Yes` `Test`  and static `No` `Test`? Are they function calls ?

Comment: `static T f(U);` declares a static function named `f` with return type `T` and 1 parameter of type `U`

Answer (score 16):

`class No { };` - defines a class, which will have an undefined size, which won't be zero (mandated by the standard)

`class Yes { No no[3]; };` - defines another class, `Yes` which will be at least 3 times as big as a `No`. So they are guaranteed to be different sizes.

`static Yes Test( B* );` - declare a function which returns a `Yes`, but don't give it a definition (we don't need one). It will match any pointer argument which is pointing to an object derived from `B`.

`static No Test( ... );` - declare a function which returns a `No` (smaller, remember?). It's an overload which will be selected if the more specific one (above) cannot be satisfied. It accepts any argument (but the other version will be selected by overload resolution in preference if the argument is derived from `B`).

`sizeof(Test(static_cast<D*>(0)))` deduces the size of the object returned by `Test` when passes a pointer to a `D`. If `D` is derived from `B`, it will be a `Yes`, otherwise it will be a `No`.

Because the 'call' is made in a non-deduced context, it is not evaluated (called), just selected and return type deduced.

<strike>The rest is probably self-explanatory.</strike> turns out it wasn't :)

So this all gets put together here:

`enum { Is = sizeof(Test(static_cast<D*>(0))) == sizeof(Yes) };`

What this is doing in a nutshell, is saying:

"declare a constant called `Is`, which will be `true` if the result of calling Test with a `D*` is a type that happens to be the same size as a `Yes`. And it will be `false` if the result of the call happens to be a type which is a different size. Because of the two overloads, above, when D is a B, or anything derived from it, `Test(D*)` will select the `Yes` version, which will return a `Yes`, which is obviously the same size as a `Yes`. If this overload is not selected, the more permissive (but lower priority) one will be. That one returns a `No`, which obviously won't be the same size as a `Yes` (by definition)."

Why is `Test(...)` 'lower priority' than `Test(B*)` (in terms of overload resolution)? Because it just is. The standard defines it to be.

Finally:

```
template <class C, class P> 
bool IsDerivedFrom() {
 return IsDerivedFromHelper<C, P>::Is;
}
```

This creates a function which will return the result of the above test for any two class types, `C` and `P`. This it will return true if `P` is derived from a `C` and false otherwise.

Comment: @pleluron yes there are many ways, but comparing sizes of two things that are mandated by the standard to have different sizes is actually very robust. The modern way is to use `std::true_type` and `std::false_type` as the return types. They have static members called `value` which are `true` and `false` respectively.

Comment: Wonderful explanation @RichardHodges , do we really need to check the sizes to find out whether they are inherited ?
Also would you please explain static_cast<D*>(0) , is 0  null pointer , what is ths deduced to when  in the  function call ?

Comment: @LearningCpp well the reason for having 2 classes of different size is so that we have some compile-time mechanism for differentiating which overload would be called, either the one that accepts a B* or the one that doesn't. In c++11 and beyond we have `constexpr` but previously we did not (and presumably constant-folding support in some ancient compilers was patchy?) So an object being a different size to another object (because it contains 3 of them) is an extremely portable way of expressing the disjunction.

Comment: so if the sizes are same, the conmpiler would not diiferentiate which overload would be called, i assumed it looks are the parameter and calls the specific overload. if possible can u explain it in steps, am relatively new to c++ actually .Thanks in advance

Comment: @LearningCpp added some more narrative.

Comment: @RichardHodges , Does it work if i change class Yes { No no[3] }  to class Yes { No no[1] } ?
This actually is successful for both 
 bool a = IsDerivedFrom<Base,Derived>();;
bool b =IsDerivedFrom<Derived,Base>();
bool c = IsDerivedFrom<Derived,Derived>(); //even this turns out to be true

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123261/discussion-between-learningcpp-and-richard-hodges).